# Display Only Play Button on Hover

Tags: mediaelement.js

We would like to use mediaelement similar to how Vimeo's player works in some instances.  If the user hovers over the video we would like to only display the play button.  But, when the user starts the video, the remaining controls appear.  Then, if the user stops the video it is then only the play button.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery to hide the Div containing the controls when the player is initated. This should hide the controls.

```
$('.mejs-controls').attr('style','visibility:hidden;');
```